# In Spring MVC How to get form object in JSP from controller ?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to get form object in jsp from controller.
JSP :: updateuser.jsp

```
  <form name="user" action="updateuser" method="post">
        <ul>
        <li>
            <label>User Name</label> <input type="text" name="userName" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Password</label> <input type="password" name="password" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>FirstName</label> <input type="text" name="firstName" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>LastName</label> <input type="text" name="lastName" />
        </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

Controller :: UpdateUserController.java

```
  @RequestMapping("/updateuser")
    public class UpdateUserController {
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,
                                       ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) {

            return new ModelAndView("updateuser","user",model);
        }
    }
```

after adding values in any field and clicking on update button. form gets submitted and in mapped POJO i'm getting value.
Now I want to show those values in fields without adding into model object (i.e. `model.addAttribute("userName", user.getUserName()`) one by one all fields). Also i dont want to use Spring tag library. How i can populate all values in form ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `@ModelAttribute` you are already putting the `User` object in the `Model`, you don't need to add it again to your returned `ModelAndView`. The model attributes are eventually added as request attributes, so you can use EL to resolve them in a `jsp`.

```
<c:out value="${user.userName}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/update" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView submitupdatevalue(@ModelAttribute("update") User update){
      ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("DisplayPageName");
       return model
    }

// ......DisplayPageName.jsp
 <td> ${update.AttributName}</td>
  //.... it should be same AttributName as submitFormpage in  DisplayPageName
```